# Customize CalendarView in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, calendarview

I am newbie in Android developing, and I have a question I'm not able to solve by the moment. I have a CalendarView in my layout and I would like to customize it by changing colors. I have this right now:

[image]

and I would like to customize it like this:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. My code is in kotlin.